# ¿Por qué mi botón SUBMIT no sirve en PHP?

Tags: php, html

buenos días. Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de 'Develoteca' sobre hacer un carrito de compras en php. Tengo este formulario:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
            $sentencia=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblproductos`");
            $sentencia->execute();
            $listaProductos=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //print_r($listaProductos);
        ?>

        <?php foreach($listaProductos as $producto){?>

                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img 
                        title="<?php echo $producto['nombre'];?>"
                        class="card-img-top" 
                        src="<?php echo $producto['imagen'];?>" alt="<?php echo $producto['nombre'];?>"

                        data-toggle="popover"
                        
                         data-content="<?php echo $producto['descripcion'];?>"
                        
                        
                        >
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <span><?php echo $producto['nombre']; ?></span>
                            <h4 class="card-title">$<?php echo $producto['precio']; ?></h4>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>

                            <form action="carrito.php" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['id'],COD,KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['nombre'],COD,KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['descripcion'],COD,KEY); ?>">
                                <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt(1,COD,KEY); ?>">
                                
                                <button type="button" 
                                    class="btn btn-primary" 
                                    name="btnAccion" 
                                    value="Agregar" 
                                    type="submit" onSubmit="<?php $mensaje="kk";?>">
                                    Agregar al carrito</button>
                            
                            </form>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
        
        
    </div>
```

Todo funcionaba correctamente hasta que pasé a clickear el botón `submit`. Cuando lo presiono no pasa nada, no sé porqué. El archivo `carrito.php` es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
$mensaje="CALVOOO";
print('funciona');
if(isset($_POST['btnAccion'])){
    
    switch($_POST['btnAccion']){

        case 'Agregar':

            if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY))){
                $id=openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY);
                $mensaje="ID correcto crack".$id;
            }else{
                $mensaje="Algo salió paila con el ID".$id;
            }

        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Me muestra el `$mensaje` pero el botón no hace nada. Ni siquiera me recarga para pensar que sí sirve, entonces no sé qué pasa :( probé usando action y apuntando directamente (aunque en el video lo dejan en blanco) y nada. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo: en el botón submit no me dí cuenta y tengo dos veces el `type="-"`, en el primero tengo `button` y en el segundo tengo tipo `submit`. Html me reconocía el primero y por eso no se mandaba.